# link directly to review page in App Store by name, not ID

Tags: ios, app-store, itunes

I am wondering how I can directly link to the review page of my iOS application, without knowing the app ID, just the name.

I know this is possible to link to the app without the app ID by using

```
itms-apps://itunes.com/apps/APPNAME
```

And you can link to the review page, but you require the app ID, ex.

```
http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?id=350212768&pageNumber=0& sortOrdering=1&type=Purple+Software&mt=8
```

So basically, can you combine these two?

Thanks.

Comment: Why is that an issue? You can get your app id as soon as you create a new app on iTunes connect (ie even before you submit it)

Comment: Never mind just saw the comments in the accepted answer :)

Comment: @Rog your comments are actually right on, this is non-question.

Comment: Yeah well I didnt know that fact. Soo :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe you can combine them the way you're wanting.

The review links need to contain an ID so it knows where to send you. The apps/APPNAME links are generous Apple short links that redirect to the actual APPID based links.

More information on all iTunes based links can be found in this awesome article.

http://bjango.com/articles/ituneslinks/

Comment: then how would I go about adding a link to my app, so it's in my app, but I haven't released it yet? Does the App ID change with updates?

Comment: The AppID will always be the same. Updates won't change it. You actually CANT change it once you've set it up in iTunes Connect.

Comment: OHHH and is this app ID available to me before I upload the app to the app store?

Comment: Yes it is :) Right inside iTunes Connect