# paid app and free / lite purchase

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I need your advice\help here.
I developed a universal App and plan to have a free and a paid version. I created two targets and managed the same code for both versions. We would like not to use the in-app purchase (for various reasons) and would like to have two distinct versions one free and one paid.
i. For the paid version - i think there isn't code that need to be implemented, we just need to submit and eventually it will be in the App store and once a user search and buy it, it will just installed itself onto the device, so nothing in the code i need to do. -- please let me know if I'm missing something.

ii. For the lite version the user will have a button that will point to the paid version and the user will download and installs it. so here do i need a code to handle the purchase or just a 'link' to our product description in the app store ? than again the app store will handle the install etc and i don't need to have any special code. correct me if I'm wrong.
that being said i need code to point to our paid product in the App store.
If you could point me to sample code to do handle that 'buy' button  (the only code sample i found was for in-app purchase that we likely not be using at this point).

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not missing anything for your first point, if you are sure that they will be two separate downloads from the AppStore.

As for your second question, no you do not need code to handle the purchase. You just need code to a link to the AppStore's page of your app. Use this code (`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.google.ca"]];`), just replace the ULR with the one to the link to the AppStore

Once you add your app into iTunes connect it will be assigned an ID, you can use this ID in a link to link to that specific page as mentioned before.

Here is a [good article](http://bjango.com/articles/ituneslinks/) talking about links to the AppStore and such. And here I had a [question regarding links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568423/link-directly-to-review-page-in-app-store-by-name-not-id) before.

Hope this helps,
SirKaydian

Comment: Thanks, i'll try that. I need to tackle the iTune connect to get an ID and then test. ty.